# Kendo UI datepicker angular directive

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI datepicker angular directive in Typescript. When I place 2 directives on one page and comment the line  `scope["ngModel"] = _utc;`, it works fine but doesn't solve my purpose. But when I uncomment the line and select the date in second directive, it clears the value of first calendar.

```
export class DateUtcDirective {

    public static $inject: string[] = ["AuthService", "propBagFilter"];

    public constructor(
        authService: Services.AuthService,
        propBagFilter: Function
        ) {
        return <ng.IDirective>{
            restrict: "A",
            template:
            "<div>" +
            "<div class='input-group'>" +
            "<input kendo-date-picker k-ng-model='ngModel' k-format='format' k-on-change='select()'/>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='input-group' ng-show='isTimeAllowed' >" +
            "<br />" +
            "<input kendo-time-picker k-ng-model='ngModel' />" +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>",
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                ngModel: "=",
                paramObject: "="
            },
            link(scope: ng.IScope, element: any, attrs: any) {
                var propBag = propBagFilter(scope["paramObject"].props);
                var authPropBag = propBagFilter(authService.currentUser.props);

                (<any>scope).select = function () {
                    if (!!propBag["IsUtc"]) {
                        console.log(scope);
                        var localDate = new Date(scope["ngModel"]);
                        var _utc = localDate.toUTCString();
                       scope["ngModel"] = _utc;
                    }
                }
                scope["isTimeAllowed"] = propBag["IsTimeAllowed"] || false;
                scope["isUtc"] = propBag["IsUtc"] || false;
                scope["format"] = authPropBag["ShortDatePattern"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think my code is not correct  scope["ngModel"] = _utc; because I am not able to select the date (even if there is only one calendar on the page ) when I uncomment this line.

Answer (score 0):

try giving id to

```
<input kendo-time-picker k-ng-model='ngModel' />
```

like

```
<input kendo-date-picker k-ng-model='ngModel' k-format='format' k-on-change='select()' id="abc1"/>
<input kendo-time-picker k-ng-model='ngModel' id="abc2" />
```